# How to use simplex method for initial estimates of parameters in Nelson-Siegel-Svensson

Tags: yield-curve, optimization

I came across a BIS [note](https://www.bis.org/publ/bppdf/bispap25l.pdf) about the estimation of the Nelson-Siegel-Svensson method. Currently, I'm trying to implement this. However, one step is not fully clear to me. Let me outline the steps of the algorithm to make the question self-contained. Although the note is very short (essentially 2 pages) and up to my question easy accessible.

The proposed algorithm works essentially the following way. For given $N$ bonds with prices $P=(P_1,\dots,P_N)$ and corresponding cash flow matrix $C\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times L}$ (so columns are maturities):

1. Calculate spot rates $r_l$ for all maturities, $r=(r_1,\dots,r_L)$
2. Calculate discount factors $d_l$, $d=(d_1,\dots,d_L)$
3. Given a cash flow matrix of all bonds, calculate the theoretical prices as $\hat{P}=Cd$
4. Using Newton-Raphson we calculate the estimated yield-to-maturity, $\hat{ytm}=(\hat{ytm}_1,\dots,\hat{ytm}_N)$

Now, for the actual objective there is the step which isn't fully clear to me. I quote directly the paper:

*5. Computing the function $\sum_{i=1}^N (ytm_i-\hat{ytm}_i(b_t,P,C))^2$ (sum of squared yield errors) using first the
Simplex algorithm and then the BHHH algorithm in order to determine a new $b_{t+1}$*

Where $b_t$ is the current set of parameters to be estimated. Before stating this they add the following sentence

*The optimisation is performed using a numerical non-linear optimisation to maximise a log-likelihood function subject to the constraint on the parameter $\beta_1$ (= overnight rate – $\beta_0$). First, we use the Simplex algorithm to compute starting values and then the Berndt, Hall, Hall and Hausmann (BHHH) algorithm
to estimate the final parameters.*

**Question**
I understand that they somehow want to use the simplex method in 5. for getting better starting values and then run a ordinary non-linear optimisation using BHHH. However, the first part using the Simplex (linear programming) is unclear to me. Maybe someone with more expertise in optimisation can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Simplex method in the paper is (very probably) Nelder-Mead direct search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method . Starting values for the model are also discussed in [A Note on 'Good' Starting Values in Numerical Optimisation](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1620083) (of which I am a co-author).

Answer (score 2):

From my memory, once you fixed the tau parametre you only need to fit a linear least square model or a simplex method they'll give you the same coefficients